# Restlet: Unable to find a converter for this representation : [application/repo.foo+xml]

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I'm trying to retrieve a resource from web service, but get this warning:

```
WARNING: Unable to find a converter for this representation : [application/repo.foo+xml]
```

And my code returns null entity. Here is code

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null));
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());

ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(path);
ChallengeScheme scheme = ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC;
ChallengeResponse auth = new ChallengeResponse(scheme, "user", "password");

resource.setChallengeResponse(auth);

Repo entity = resource.get(Repo.class);
System.out.println(entity);
```

*UPDATE*

My attempts which unfortunately don't work:

1. `resource.getRequestAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", new MediaType("application", "application/repo.foo+xml"));`
2. `resource.setAttribute("Content-Type", "application/repo.foo+xml");`

Comment: It's being sent back with a content type jackson doesn't recognise.  What does the full response look like?  It it's JSON then the server needs to set the correct content type for it.

Comment: How can I set Content-Type in Restlet? this one `resource.setAttribute("Content-Type", "application/repo.foo+xml");` doesn't work.

Comment: That sets the client accent type.  The server can ignore it if it wants.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in your question.

You are writing a client.  You can tell the client to set an accept header.  Put simply, this is a hint to the server about what content type you'd like the response to be in.  JSON, HTML, XML, whatever.  The server can either honour this, send you it's best guess or ignore it completely.

You can try setting the accept header to "application/javascript" and see how it responds.  If it continues to send "application/repo.foo+xml" then you will probably be able to parse it with the jackson xml databind package.  You may have to register the media type and converter with the client so it knows which converter to use to serialise the object.

Comment: In fact it was the question how to register a custom `MediaType`. I send a lot of time on research, but I didn't find any solution for that. Now I see that `Restlet` is very bad documented library.

Comment: Restlet in action is an excellent book.  I'll check it for you later. I've done this before on the server side, I'll see if it works the same.